# Как сделать выборку данных из двух таблиц одним запросом (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы (**articles**, **comments**).

Перед выборкой у меня есть значение **Id**.

Из первой таблицы при помощи **where** я делаю выборку:

```
select * from `articles` 
where `Id` = '9' or `ParentId` = '9'
```

Из полученных данных получаю все **Id** и при помощи

```
select * from `comments` where `ArticleId` in (Id1, Id2, Id3 ...)
```

Получаю все комментарии, относящиеся к этим статьям.

Возможно ли это объединить в один запрос к БД (комментариев к каждой статье может быть много)?

Нужно получить и все статьи и все комментарии одним запросом

Comment: Не поленитесь и почитайте про JOIN - ну хоть что-нибудь...

Comment: вам точно нужны комментарии ко всем статьям, а не только к той где id=9 ?

Comment: @Akina хорошо, буду изучать. Спасибо.

Comment: @teran ага, нужно все и сразу)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from `comments` where `ArticleId` in (select id from `articles` 
where `Id` = '9' or `ParentId` = '9')
```

Comment: А где данные из `articles`? автору они тоже нужны - сто пудов...

Comment: так он же не указал ничего. пусть теперь сам додумывает

Comment: Боюсь, что не додумает, как конвертировать условие в источник данных - там же в области знаний о связывании конь не валялся...

Comment: Да, подправил вопрос. Нужно получить и все статьи и все комментарии одним запросом